# seed user and user role issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, seeding

I am trying to seed my database with an initial user and user role and am having issues in doing so. After reviewing similar posts on SO, I've ended up with the following in my seed method:

```
if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "founder"))
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = "founder"};

        manager.Create(user, "ChangeItAsap!");
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "AppAdmin");
    }
```

and my ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin,CustomUserRole,CustomUserClaim>
  {

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
      // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
      var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
      // Add custom user claims here
      return userIdentity;
    }
  }
```

My issue is that I am getting compilation errors on `ApplicationUser` saying that

> The type RecipeManager.Models.ApplicationUser cannot be used as a type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method `'UserManager<TUser>'`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `RecipeManager.Models.ApplicationUser` to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<string>`

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationUser` MUST to implement the `IUser<string>` interface. This is the type allowed in the user manager. Most likely the issue is related to the `string` data type of the key. The default scaffolding process assumes `string` as it is more generic data type. You need to change either the type of the key in the `ApplicationUser` class to string, or inherit `IUser<int>` or whatever type you use in the `UserManager`.